# Detect the first time an Activity is opened on this session

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to detect the first time an activity is called every time the user launches the app:

- App is launched
- Activity X is called for the first time

  - Do something
- Activity Y, Z are called many times
- Activity X is called again many times

  - Do nothing

... so "do something" has to be called only if the app was closed (or killed) and then be launched again.

Comment: What is the "do something" exactly?

Comment: Can you explain why you need this? There could be another way simple way to do it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I usually use `static boolean` variable inside the activity as a flag. Then, inside `onCreate()`, test the variable; if it's `true`, do something and flip the flag.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static boolean RUN_ONCE = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        runOnce();
    }

    private void runOnce() {
        if (RUN_ONCE) {
            RUN_ONCE = false;

            // do something
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: There is a chance that the static variable to be cleared when the app goes background and the foreground app needs memory.

Comment: @AndrewT. for me it is always true and it doesn't go to the else statement. Do you know how to make that.

Comment: "runOnce()" will run once but when you kill the activity (eg. back button) the static bool RUN_ONCE is kept in memory and so when you start the activity again(fresh start) - runOnce() will not be triggered

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
private static boolean isApplicationBroughtToBackground(final Activity activity) {
      ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
      List tasks = null;
      try {
        tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
      } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Missing required permission: \"android.permission.GET_TASKS\".", e);
        return false;
      }
      if (tasks != null && !tasks.isEmpty()) {
        ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
        try {
          PackageInfo pi = activity.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
          for (ActivityInfo activityInfo : pi.activities) {
            if(topActivity.getClassName().equals(activityInfo.name)) {
              return false;
            }
          }
        } catch( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Package name not found: " + activity.getPackageName());
          return false; // Never happens.
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

when calling from an other activity pass a Boolean extra with intent. and check this intent in your on start

```
     @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            boolean firstTime= getIntent().getBooleanExtra("firstTime", true);
    if(firstTime)
{
//do something
}
else
{
//do something
}
```

Answer (score -4):

use sqlite

```
create table first (f INTEGER DEFAULT 0)
public int getFirst(){ codes... }
public void setFirst(){ codes... }


int x = db.getFirst();

    if(x == 0){
        db.setFirst(); //update f column to 1
        DO SOMETHING
    }
```