# Is there a better way to load a picture in android studio?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-storage

I am making an app using Java in android studio, and in it I want users to have the option to set a custom profile picture. I'm using firebase storage to store the images for the PFPs, and taking them from there every time I load it, but it always takes around half a second or so to load the profile picture: [gif of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyC9r.gif)

Here's my code for loading the pfp in the homepage (I am using de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView to make the ImageView circular):

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {

de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView pfpImage;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

pfpImage = findViewById(R.id.pfpImg);

Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("UserEmail")) {
            String userEmail = intent.getExtras().getString("UserEmail");
            StorageReference userPfp = DBRef.refStorage.child("ProfileImages/Users/" + userEmail.replace(".",",")); //DBRef is a class I created to reference all Firebase related objects.
            userPfp.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    Picasso.with(HomePage.this).load(uri).into(pfpImage); // I am using com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2 to load the image from the Uri.
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(HomePage.this, "Profile Picture Loading Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        else
            pfpImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.doggo);
}
}
```

Is there some better way to load/store the pictures so they appear when the page loads?

**EDIT:** I managed to negate this by not loading from Firebase every time the activity is opened, but only the first time and saving it, using an idea from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042510/detect-the-first-time-an-activity-is-opened-on-this-session/19042705)

Comment: How big is the image in size?

Answer (score 0):

There is other library named glide that can load picture faster when the page loads.
Here is the link for the reference.

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Displaying-Images-with-the-Glide-Library

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to be loading around the same rate as Picasso. Maybe it's because I'm accessing the pictures from Firebase Storage constantly, so it takes time?